# Access #TempTable declared in child procedure in parent procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have nested stored procedures and I need to create a LOCAL TEMP TABLE in child procedure and be able to use it in the parent procedure.

EX:

Parent procedure:

```
EXEC ChildProcedure
SELECT * FROM #TempTable
```

Child procedure:

```
CREATE TABLE #TempTable (Field1 VARCHAR(1000),Field2 VARCHAR(1000))
INSERT INTO #TempTable (Field1,Field2) VALUES ('1','2')
```

When I try this, SQL says:

> Invalid Object Name '#TempTable'

Is there any way to achieve this without GLOBAL TEMP TABLES ?

Comment: It looks like you want to share information between stored procedures.  Erland Sommarskog has an excellent blog on this topic:  http://www.sommarskog.se/share_data.html.

Comment: Does the child procedure *have* to be the one that *creates* the table? Having the parent create it and the child populate it is trivial to achieve. The other way round, not so much, [since](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174979.aspx):  "A local temporary table created in a stored procedure is dropped automatically when the stored procedure is finished"

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Yes I reached your aproach too but I wanted to know if there is another way to do it. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well I think I finally found the answer to my question in https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174979.aspx.

> A local temporary table created in a stored procedure is dropped automatically when the stored procedure is finished. **The table can be referenced by any nested stored procedures executed by the stored procedure that created the table. The table cannot be referenced by the process that called the stored procedure that created the table.**

So the answer to my own question is NO. I can't do that in that way.

The best approach (as @Damien_The_Unbeliever said) is to create the table in the parent procedure and populate it inside the child procedure.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of Procedure you can create a table valued function like this and use a

```
Create Function ChiledFunction ()
Returns  @TempTable Table  (Field1 VARCHAR(1000),Field2 VARCHAR(1000)) AS 
Begin
INSERT INTO @TempTable (Field1,Field2) VALUES ('1','2')
Return 
end
```

and parent procedure is here

```
Create Procedure ParentProc 
As
 begin 
   select * from dbo.ChiledFunction()

end
```

Comment: @N.Molderf this is a solution and it could be any thing and it is not a scope for procedure only .

Comment: this function you can use anywhere not only in parent procedure

Comment: This is a answer of the question I think we should not continue on this topic because this is a public forum .